# How to prove this inequality $f(a+b)\leq f(a) +f(b)$ for $\frac{f(x)}x$ monotone decreasing

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, fractions

$f(x)$ is defined on$(0,\infty)$, and $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is monotone decreasing, how to prove  $\forall a>0,b>0$ $f(a+b)\leq f(a) +f(b)$. Thanks pretty much in advance

Comment: Wonder whether having a negative points implication for poster or answers, if a post is closed as duplicate would help correct behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{f(a)}{a}\geq\dfrac{f(a+b)}{a+b}\\
&\dfrac{f(b)}{b}\geq\dfrac{f(a+b)}{a+b},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
&f(a)\geq\dfrac{a}{a+b}\cdot f(a+b)\\
&f(b)\geq\dfrac{b}{a+b}\cdot f(a+b),
\end{align*}
adding together, we have
\begin{align*}
f(a)+f(b)\geq\left(\dfrac{a}{a+b}+\dfrac{b}{a+b}\right)f(a+b)=f(a+b).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Let $a>b>0$.
Thus,
$$f(a+b)<(a+b)\frac{f(a)}{a}=f(a)+\frac{f(a)}{a}\cdot b<f(a)+\frac{f(b)}{b}\cdot b=f(a)+f(b).$$